# CSS/HTML: Appearing div on hover not working

Tags: html, css

What I want is I have an invisible div somewhere, and then when you hover over it it appears (maybe with a transition, not necessary.). So I've tried the following:

-- CSS code

```
div.appearingBox {
display: none;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
}

div.appearingBox:hover {
display: block;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
border: 1px solid rgb(0,0,255);
}
```

-- HTML code (Added)

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="appearingBox">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This doesn't work... Please help!

Comment: Trying for something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/2K6JE/1/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need a wrapping div.  Because it's not visible, it can't respond to :hover.  Note that the `:hover` is on the wrapper instead of the element itself.  That is because the wrapper is "visible" but transparent.

http://jsfiddle.net/Cs87c/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="appearingBox">
    <div>Hidden</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.appearingBox div {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

.appearingBox:hover div {
    visibility: visible;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    border: 1px solid rgb(0,0,255);
}
```

(Edited to a cleaner version)

Comment: I agree, nice job on figuring this out.

Comment: I have updated Davy8's answer to add a transition...  http://jsfiddle.net/Cs87c/2/

Comment: @superUntitled Such a simple thing but makes it so much more elegant i have been using this on all my hovers for a while now and wish more dev would do the same. great addition :)